# Getting the data from form and adding it to grid using Extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have created a form panel and a grid.I am using Extjs. Now I want the user entered data to be inserted into a grid on clicking the save button. How to get the data from form into the grid?

Answer (score 0):

When the button is pressed, you need to perform a CRUD operation on a record in the store that the grid is displaying. The grid will automatically re-render itself when a record in the store is changed.